# Difference between QML's Component and Instantiator?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, qqmlcomponent

The QML types [`Component`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html) and [`Instantiator`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-instantiator.html) appear to do similar things; create QML objects on demand, as opposed to when parsing their definitions.  **So what's the difference?**  Why would I want to use one over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `Instantiator` creates instances of the given `Component` - one for each model-entry given in `model`. It's similar to the Repeater.

A `Component` is a Class. A `Instantiator` is sort of a Factory for the given Component.

Comment: But can't I just create instances of a `Component` without an `Instantiator`?

Comment: There are multiple Possibilities, choose which one fits best for you: You can use a [`Loader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) for a single Instance, a [`Repeater'](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-repeater.html) for multiple instances. Since QtQml2.2 there is also the [`Instantiator'](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-instantiator.html) which is a Repeater that can load asynchronously. You can also use `Component.createrObject()` or `Component.incubateObject()` which are attached to every `Item`

Comment: You can imagine `Component` as a prototype of the object. Like a `class MyClass{}` in `C++`. `Instantiator` is a real object which creates items. So these items are parented to `Instantiator`. When you create *instance* of `Component` you should set a parent.